# Solving Poisson equations as mixed Laplace using $RT_0-P_0$ pair

Tags: finite-element, poisson, design-patterns, mixed-formulation

I'm trying to solve  \begin{cases} - \Delta p=f \text{ in } \Omega\\ p=0 \text{ on } \partial \Omega \end{cases} with in $\Omega = [-1,1]^2$ by writing it as

\begin{cases} u + \nabla p=0 \\ -\operatorname{div}(u) = -f  \\ p = 0 \text{ on } \partial \Omega \end{cases}

whose weak form is \begin{cases}(v,u) - (\operatorname{div}(v),p) = 0  \qquad \forall v \in V\\ -(\operatorname{div}(u),q) = -(f,q) \qquad \forall q \in Q\end{cases}

where $V=H^{\operatorname{div}}(\Omega)$ and $Q=L^2(\Omega)$.
To solve it, I decided to use the inf-sup stable couple $V_h=RT_0$ (for the velocity) and $Q=P_0$ for the pressure. The basis functions for $RT_0$ in the reference triangle $\hat{K}$ are $$\hat{\phi_1} = \sqrt{2}(\hat{x},\hat{y})$$ $$\hat{\phi_2} = (-1+\hat{x},\hat{y})$$ $$\hat{\phi_3} = (\hat{x},-1+\hat{y})$$

In terms of finite element matrices, we have a saddle point problem and the element matrices $A^K$ and $B^K$ ($K$ is a triangle) have components:

$$a_{ij}^K = \frac{1}{|\det(B_K)|}\int_{\hat{K}} [\text{sign}_i^K][ \text{sign}_j^K] B_K \hat{\phi_i} \cdot  B_K \hat{\phi_j}$$

$$b_j^K=-\frac{1}{|\det(B_K)|} \int_{\hat{K}} [\text{sign}_j^K] \operatorname{div}(\hat{\phi_j})$$

where $B_K$ is the matrix in the classical affine mapping $F_K:\hat{K} \rightarrow K$, $F_K(\hat{\boldsymbol{x}}) = B_K \hat{\boldsymbol{x}} + \boldsymbol{b_K}$.

---

I've been implementing this in MatLab for two days, but the **condition number of the whole saddle point system is infinite**.

- The boundary condition $p=0 \text{ on } \partial \Omega$ should be weakly imposed, so I did not change the matrix after the `assemble()` function. If that is correct, then the problem must be inside my `assemble()` function, in particular in the distribution of the entries of $B$. Since I have $1$ DoF per triangle for the pressure, I have a 3x1 vector for each element $K$.

I think the following code is really "didactic":

- here the inputs `p,t` are the result of the MatLab function `initmesh`, and `force` is a function handle with the forcing term.
- `RT_shapes` is a function that evaluates at the points the RT basis functions and also computes the divergence for each function (which happens to be a constant vector $[2 \sqrt{2},2,2]$)
- In my tests, I am assuming $f$ s.t. the solution is $(x^2-1)(y^2-1)$, which indeed satisfies homogeneous Dirichlet.

Do you spot any error in my reasoning? I really don't see it, and any hint is really welcome!

---

```
function [A,B,F] = assemble(p,t,force)
[rspoints,qwgts] = GaussPoints(4);
np = size(p,2); %N points
nt = size(t,2); %N elements
A = sparse(np,np); %N_DoFs x N_DoFs
B = sparse(nt,np); % N_triangles x N_DoFs
F = zeros(nt,1);

for K=1:nt
    l2g = t(1:3,K); %global node indices for element K
    tmp = l2g([2 3 1]) - l2g([3 1 2]);
    signs = tmp ./ abs(tmp);



x = p(1,l2g); %x coords
y = p(2,l2g); %y coords

BK = [x(2)-x(1), x(3)-x(1);y(2)-y(1),y(3)-y(1)];
bK = [x(1);y(1)];
detBK = det(BK);

detBK_inv = 1/(abs(detBK));
%% Loop over quadrature points
for q=1:length(qwgts)
    r = rspoints(q,1); %x coordinate q-th quadrature point
    s = rspoints(q,2); %y coordinate q-th quadrature point
    [phi,divphi] = RT_shapes(r,s);
    
    JxW=qwgts(q)*detBK/2.0;
    physical_coords = BK*[r;s] + bK; %physical coordinates of the current quadrature points
    xp = physical_coords(1);
    yp = physical_coords(2);
    
    val_rhs = -force(xp,yp)*1.0*JxW;
    F(K) = F(K) + val_rhs;
    
    
    for i=1:3
        for j=1:3
            val_A =  signs(i)*signs(j)*detBK_inv* dot(BK*phi(:,i),BK*phi(:,j))*qwgts(q);
            A(l2g(i),l2g(j)) = A(l2g(i),l2g(j)) + val_A;
            
        end
        val_B = - signs(i)* detBK_inv*divphi(i)*qwgts(q);
        B(K,l2g(i)) = B(K, l2g(i)) + val_B;
        
    end
    
    
end

end
```

---

## EDIT

---

@knl spotted a fatal typo in my code above, i.e. the indexing given by `l2g` was the one referred to vertex, not to triangle edges. I used a suitable routine, found in the appendix of the book by Larson-Bengzon, named `Tri2Edge` that numbers the edges of a triangle mesh.

Now, the following code is the last version.

- I'm using the indices of the edges to decide which entry of the matrices $A$ and $B$ has to be filled.
- Let $N_t$ the number of elements, and $N_e$ the number of edges. The matrix $A$ is a $N_e \times N_e$, while $B$ is a $N_e \times N_t$. The $F$ term in the rhs has size $N_t$.
- Again, homogeneous Dirichlet BC are assumed.
- Crucially, I noticed that in [my reference paper for the implementation](https://www.siam.org/Portals/0/Publications/SIURO/Vol12/S01743.pdf), the formula $(8)$ for $b_j^K$ is not what they implemented, since if you go to the first snippet, you may see that they multiplied by `detJ` the entries of $B$, while in that formula they divide their divergence by `detJ`. I don't know why, but if I do not multiply by `detJ`, I obtain the correct solution, as can be seen by the following graph for the pressure, and the correct $L^2$ convergence for the pressure (order $1$, as I am using 1 DoF per triangle).

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

[image]

---

```
function [A,B,F] = assemble(p,t,t2e,force)
[rspoints,qwgts] = GaussPoints(4);
nt = size(t,2); %N_triangles
ne = max(t2e(:)); %N_edges
A = sparse(ne,ne); %N_edges x N_edges
B = sparse(nt,ne); % N_triangles x N_edges
F = zeros(nt,1); %N_triangles

for K=1:nt
    l2g = t(1:3,K); %global node indices for element K
    edges = t2e(K,:);%global edges indices for element K
    tmp = l2g([2 3 1]) - l2g([3 1 2]);
    signs = tmp ./ abs(tmp);
    
    x = p(1,l2g); %x coords
    y = p(2,l2g); %y coords
    
    BK = [x(2)-x(1), x(3)-x(1);y(2)-y(1),y(3)-y(1)];
    bK = [x(1);y(1)];
    detBK = det(BK);
    
    detBK_inv = 1/abs(detBK);
    %% Loop over quadrature points
    for q=1:length(qwgts)
        r = rspoints(q,1); %x coordinate q-th quadrature point
        s = rspoints(q,2); %y coordinate q-th quadrature point
        [phi,divphi] = RT_shapes(r,s);
        
        JxW=qwgts(q)*detBK;
        physical_coords = BK*[r;s] + bK; %physical coordinates of the current quadrature points
        xp = physical_coords(1);
        yp = physical_coords(2);
        
        val_rhs = -force(xp,yp)*1.0*JxW;
        F(K) = F(K) + val_rhs;
        
        
        for i=1:3
            for j=1:3
                val_A =  detBK_inv*dot(signs(i)*BK*phi(:,i),signs(j)*BK*phi(:,j))*qwgts(q);
                A(edges(i),edges(j)) = A(edges(i),edges(j)) + val_A;
                
            end
            val_B = -signs(i)*divphi(i)*qwgts(q);
            B(K,edges(i)) = B(K, edges(i)) + val_B;
            
        end
        
        
    end
    
end
```

Comment: What is the nullity of your global matrix? How do you make sure that the BC for the pressure is satisfied (in the weak sense)?

Comment: Before we run code for RT/Hdiv space, we run a unit test, checking if the volume integral divergence is equal to the flux on the boundary (.i.e. Gauss's theorem). That will validate your base functions/integration and Piola transform. We set the coefficient of every base to one. Our code is generic for arbitrary base order, see
http://mofem.eng.gla.ac.uk/mofem/html/hcurl_divergence_operator_2d_8cpp-example.html

Comment: I found a MATLAB implementation: https://www.mathematik.hu-berlin.de/~cc/download/public/software/documentation/CBaCCMFEM.pdf

Comment: @ZoltánCsáti The nullity for $B'$ returns a matrix with 3 columns. I know that it should return a single vector $1$, or a scaled copy of $1$, so the problem must be there. For what concerns the pressure, I was assuming that the condition $p=0$ on $\partial \Omega$ is automatically satisfied since the term on the weak form has been eliminated

Comment: @ZoltánCsáti I've checked everything again and I can't spot the problem. My snippet wants just to compute the local contributions to the mass matrix  $A$ and the "divergence" $B$. The resulting global matrix should not be post-processed, since I want homogeneous Dirichlet on the whole domain. I'm really puzzled honestly

Comment: @bob_bill I myself never implemented Ravier-Thomas elements. Sometimes it helps if you can associate a physical meaning to the mathematical problem. For instance, in linear elasticity, I know what can possibly cause the non-trivial null space of the element matrices and the global matrix as well. Here, I do not know. Another tip is to use `null(A, 'r')` in MATLAB so that you can interpret better the vectors that span the null space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a different kind of indexing in `l2g`. Right now you are using the indices of the global vertices when deciding which rows and columns to fill. This causes wrong entries to be summed when building the global matrix. You need to instead uniquely index all edges of your mesh and use those indices in `l2g`.

Comment: Honestly, I just found the expression for those functions and used them. I took them from https://www.siam.org/Portals/0/Publications/SIURO/Vol12/S01743.pdf (page 250)

Comment: Alright, in the DOF you are dividing by the length of the edge. Then it's fine I guess.

Comment: Okay. For what concerns the homogeneous Dirichlet BC, how should I impose them? In my code, I just assembled the global block matrix and solved using that matrix, without any postprocess, because the term with the Dirichlet BC in the weak form is identically $0$. @knl

Comment: Zero Dirichlet is a natural BC and automatically satisfied.

Comment: So, correct me if I'm wrong, in my case I shouldn't post process the matrices $A,B$ after the assembly, right? The problem then must be in how I assemble $B$, since its nullspace is *not* made by a multiple of the vector $1$. Maybe the problem is in how I considered  the DoFs for $B$ in the snippet @knl

Comment: No postprocessing unless you want to do Neumann boundary condition.

Comment: Uhm, then there must be an error in my assembly routine. I have, in each triangle $K$, three DoFs for the velocity $\boldsymbol{u}$ whose global index is given by the `l2g` vector, and one for the pressure. On each velocity DoF (corresponding to the vertex of the triangle) I am assuming to have a RT basis function, so the "divergence" matrix is a 3 by 1 in each $K$, while the mass matrix is a 3by3. That's correct, right? @knl

Comment: RT0 basis functions are one per edge, not one per vertex. The indexing is different.

Comment: Looking at your code, that could explain the error. What you need to do is to uniquely index all edges in your mesh and then use those instead of the vertex indices when assembling. I edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: You spotted the biggest typo. Thanks a lot. I edited my question with my results and the new code. It seems to work (see solution and EOC w.r.t DoFs), even if I do not understand what should be the local contribution to the matrix $B$, since in the paper I am using it's not clear to me what's going on. If you could clarify this last aspect, then I have no other questions (I opened a bounty so to give you more credits, as you looked also the code)

Comment: Usually you multiply by detJ because of the integral transformation. The integral is transformed to the reference element and, as a consequence, we multiply by detJ. However, Piola transformation requires dividing by detJ so those two cancel out and that's why your approach works.

Comment: The code in your reference is a bit unreadable due to the unnecessarily complicated vectorization. However, it seems in the first snippet they multiply by detJ and in the second snippet they divide by detJ so the end result should be the same. The equation (9) is really confusing because the divergence has no "hat" implying that it would be in the global coordinates. Somehow I feel that shouldn't be the case so I assume they have a typo somewhere in the formulae.

Comment: So basically we have $\int_K \operatorname{div}(\Phi)p(x) dx$ and since $x = F_K(\hat{x})$ and we $$\int_{\hat{K}} \operatorname{div}(\frac{1}{\det(B_K))} \hat{\Phi}(\hat{x})) \hat{q_j}(\hat{x}) |\det(B_K)| d \hat{x}$$

What is not clear to me is why we're allowed to put that $\frac{1}{\det(B_K)}$ inside the divergence, instead of the usual affine map. This is not mathematically correct, right? @knl

Comment: I'm not sure what is going on. The contravariant Piola transformation is defined as
$$\frac{1}{\det(B_K)} B_K \hat{\Psi}(\hat{x}) = \Psi(x).$$
This implies that the divergence transforms as
$$\frac{1}{\det(B_K)} \hat{\mathrm{div}}\hat{\Psi} = \mathrm{div}\Psi.$$

Comment: Sorry for asking again, but the "dx" term with $\det(B_K)$ (which simplifies with the $\det(B_K)$ in the divergence term) then will appear because we're still using the transformation $x = B_K \hat{x} + b_K$, i.e. $x=F_K(\hat{x})$ when we come back to $\hat{K}$, right? What is puzzling me is that is seems that we're applying two transformations: Piola and $F_K$. I understand the definition of Piola transformation, but I don't see how the change of variable from $K$ to $\hat{K}$ is working in this case. @knl

Comment: Yes, we are applying two transformations. $F_K$ defines the shape of the global triangle. Piola makes sure that the derivative DOFs are preserved through the transformation. You can think about it in 1D. If you have $f(u) = u(a)$ as a DOF we can transform basis function as $\psi(x) = \hat{\psi}(\hat{x})$ and, as a consequence, $f(\hat{\psi}) = f(\psi)$. However, if you have $g(u) = u^\prime(a)$ as a DOF we would have $g(\hat{\psi}) \not= g(\psi)$. Hence, we cannot do $\psi(x) = \hat{\psi}(\hat{x})$ and need to invent something else. (Piola preserves normal derivatives in 2D and 3D).

Comment: Note that even in standard $H^1$ FEM we are doing two transformations, the other one is just so trivial that you never think about it as a transformation. ($\psi(x) = \hat{\psi}(\hat{x})$)

Comment: You're right. Thanks so much @knl, you've been really helpful. I accepted your answer. I've seen you're developing a python library. Is there any reference/book that describes FEM implementations from the Mathematical perspective (i.e. by thinking in terms of DoFs, not like engineers) that you've used to develop it, or is it "only experience"?

Comment: I read so many books that I've lost count. There isn't a single source I used. However, reading books by people who have developed codes themselves and comparing them to some of the more mathematical texts have helped me a lot. Some examples are Demkowicz' books, Larson book is very nice although the codes are not very fast, Wolfgang Bangerth's lecture notes, FEniCS book is quite good overview of modern thinking. The mathematical side is: Braess, Johnson, Ern-Guermond books, Brenner-Scott, and Boffi-Brezzi-Fortin. However, I also learn a lot from colleagues in academia so hard to say.

Comment: Thanks a lot @knl, for the mathematical side I was already using those classics, while I have to say FEniCS book was new to me, but really cool (I already saw most of Bangerth's lectures notes). Your suggestions are really precious, thanks again :-)